# Can we have a setter member function as const referenced from a const object?

Tags: c++, constants, setter, pass-by-const-reference

I have a class like this :

```
class XYZ {
public :
  bool var1 = true;
  ABC *var2 = nullptr;

public :
  XYZ() = default;

  void SetVar1(bool flag)
  {   var1 = flag;  }

  void SetVar2(ABC *abc)
  {   var2 = abc;  }
}
```

I want to know that if my objects for XYZ are referenced as const everywhere in my codebase, 
can I use these setters? 
P.S. I have tried with const Setters and it doesn't work 
(I knew it doesn't make much sense but I was stuck in the compilation error so tried it anyway)

Comment: Why are you trying to call setters for constant objects?!

Comment: Actually I made it const to avoid having overloaded calls and use default parameters as the objects are passed by reference. now I realize it is coming back to haunt me :-O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once u make ur object const u can't change value of any varables in this object